# Stack overflow exception when moving between fragment very quickly

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I am getting the following stack trace when I quickly switch between fragments really fast (Fragment transaction without adding to backstack) . (5 fragments per second). Any idea why this is occuring ?

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPrepareOptionsPanel(FragmentActivity.java:472)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:461)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:294)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:541)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:89)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(Too
```

Comment: you got solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflowError occurs when your application gets into infinite loop. In your output we can see that `onPreparePanel` is called many times before catching the error.

Try to check what can be wrong with `onPreparePanel` and what could trigger it so it starts looping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The onPreparePanel  is part of the android support library and I do not have any specific overriding of that in my application. And  there are no loops that I am using to move to different fragments.  I only get the error when I  manually change the fragments very fast. And it seems like I do not get the error if I move fragments slowly.

Comment: One another thing to note  is that I am setting the action bar (Using ToolBar) for each of the new fragments that I am creating (Which is required for my app as I want the tool bar to move along with the transitions between fragments).

Comment: I am sorry, I am not used to working with ToolBar, but I think that updating actionbar with every new fragment can be the issue. Unfortunately I am not sure, how to solve it. You say that it occurs only when you manipulate fragments quickly, so maybe adding some delay before updating actionbar would help?? :-)